# View mercurial history with straightline development smashed

Tags: mercurial

I'm interested in viewing the topology of my branches, ideally in a pretty way (a la graphlog).  For example I want to see how many (open) branches there are, when they split, the last time they merged to and from each other, etc.  I am not interested in *all* the merges between them, nor straight line development on each branch.

This is useful when looking at forks on bitbucket for example.  Github's network graph helps, but often the branch structure is drowned out by straightline development and/or frequent merges.

I thought that perhaps I could use revsets like

```
hg glog --rev "head() or merge() or branch_points()"
```

but then `glog` shows all revisions in between, not to mention the fact that I couldn't figure out how to specify branch_points() i.e. revisions which have more than one child.

Is there an extentsion for mercurial (or another DVCS) which can approximate my desires?  If not is there a better way to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following patch adds the branchpoint revset to Mercurial. It currently only applies to Mercurial 2.2, but there it works nicely.

I don’t know if I‘ll have time to push for inclusion quickly. You could go to the mailing list and offer to get it ready for inclusion (that would save me that work).

The revision is also in https://bitbucket.org/ArneBab/hg-stable

```
# HG changeset patch
# User bab@draketo.de
# Date 1343931127 -7200
# Branch stable
# Node ID f5e211663739e31f2e476c43992ee5335f9d8146
# Parent  00182b3d087909e3c3ae44761efecdde8f319ef3
revsets: added branchpoint() for revisions with more than one child.

Reason: Get very terse information via

    hg glog --rev "head() or merge() or branchpoint()"

diff -r 00182b3d0879 -r f5e211663739 mercurial/revset.py
--- a/mercurial/revset.py       Tue May 01 19:09:15 2012 +0900
+++ b/mercurial/revset.py       Thu Aug 02 20:12:07 2012 +0200
@@ -710,6 +710,15 @@
     cl = repo.changelog
     return [r for r in subset if cl.parentrevs(r)[1] != -1]

+def branchpoint(repo, subset, x):
+    """``branchpoint()``
+    Changeset has more than one child.
+    """
+    # i18n: "merge" is a keyword
+    getargs(x, 0, 0, _("branchpoint takes no arguments"))
+    cl = repo.changelog
+    return [r for r in subset if cl.children(repo[r].node())[1:]]
+
 def minrev(repo, subset, x):
     """``min(set)``
     Changeset with lowest revision number in set.
@@ -1137,6 +1146,7 @@
     "bisected": bisected,
     "bookmark": bookmark,
     "branch": branch,
+    "branchpoint": branchpoint,
     "children": children,
     "closed": closed,
     "contains": contains,
```

Comment: Okay, I finally looked at this.  It seems to be much slower than, say, merge(), but it appears to work.  I don't know much about mercurial development, but I'll see if I can get on the mailing list soon.  All that's needed is tests right?

Comment: I sent a patch to the list, but I haven't see it show up in the archives yet.

Comment: did it get into the archives, now? If not, you can just send it to me and I’ll forward it to the devel-list. arne_bab -ät- web -dot- de

Comment: Yeah, it's in the archives.  Thread starts at http://www.selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2012-August/043486.html

Comment: This made it into mercurial 2.4 (with improvements from the developers).

Answer (score 2):

```
  $ hg log -Gr "merge() + head()"
```

Comment: Actually, mercurial 2.4 has `branchpoint()` now so that can be added.

Comment: I try **hg log -Gr "branchpoint()"** but it fail with *hg: parse error: not a function: branchpoint* That do you mean?

Comment: Yes, that what I meant (well you want `hg log -Gr "merge()+head()+branchpoint()"` .  You might need to upgrade to a newer version since 2.4 [came out in Nov. 2012](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WhatsNew#Mercurial_2.4_.282012-11-1.29)

Comment: Ok, I use 2.2 which seems have no such function.